how to do right shift rounding middle towards even
For doing a right shift of unsigned values with rounding, the following functions work for me:
unsigned rshift_round_down(unsigned x, unsigned a) {
  return x >> a;
}

unsigned rshift_round_up(unsigned x, unsigned a) {
  return (x >> a) + ((x & ((1U << a) - 1)) != 0);
}

unsigned rshift_round_halfway(unsigned x, unsigned a) {
  if (a == 0) return x;
  return (x >> a) + ((x >> (a - 1)) & 1);
}

unsigned rshift_round_towards_even(unsigned x, unsigned a) {
  if (a == 0) return x;
  return (x >> a) + ((x >> (a - ((x & ((1U << a) - 1)) != 1 << (a - 1)))) & 1);
}

Is there a simpler but equivalent implementation of rshift_round_towards_even?
Please note that the allowed values for a are these: 0 <= a && a < sizeof(unsigned) * 8. Thus these functions don't have to work for very large values of a.
Example inputs and outputs:

rshift_round_towards_even(60, 2) == 15
rshift_round_towards_even(61, 2) == 15
rshift_round_towards_even(62, 2) == 16  (middle towards even is up)
rshift_round_towards_even(63, 2) == 16
rshift_round_towards_even(64, 2) == 16
rshift_round_towards_even(65, 2) == 16
rshift_round_towards_even(66, 2) == 16  (middle towards even is down)
rshift_round_towards_even(67, 2) == 17
rshift_round_towards_even(68, 2) == 17
rshift_round_towards_even(69, 2) == 17
rshift_round_towards_even(70, 2) == 18  (middle towards even is up)
rshift_round_towards_even(71, 2) == 18
rshift_round_towards_even(72, 2) == 18
rshift_round_towards_even(73, 2) == 18


What is it supposed to do? "right shift with rounding" doesn't make much sense

Side note: a - 1 is a problem for you when a is 0.  Consider implementing rshift_round_halfway() as a ? (((x >> (a - 1)) + 1) >> 1) : x.

@JohnBollinger Same problem for a - 1 in rshift_round_towards_even also?

Yes, @CraigEstey, but I haven't worked out a good alternative for that one yet.  That is, after all, the actual question posed.

Side note: To start, I was looking to improve round_up because of the != adding branching (my attempt failed), but, I looked at the disassembly (with -O2) and found that the function used setne so it was branchless. Is this the way to view it? The best generated asm rather than the C code?

@EugeneSh.: An unsigned right shift by a bits is the same as division by 1 << a. The function should do that division, with rounding middle towards even.

A foundation for rounding up is (x + (1u << a) - 1u) >> a, but you have to deal with the possibility of wrapping. If using a wider type is acceptable, changing 1u to 1ull may suffice.

Similarly, rounding to nearest, ties upward, can be (x + (1u << a-1)) >> a.

Then rounding to nearest, ties to even, can be (x + (1u << a-1) - 1u + (x >> a & 1u)) >> a.

@pts, Tip: when looking for a better solution, posting a test harness that rates the alternate solution makes for a clear target.

I've synthesized a test/benchmark harness in my answer below.

This Q&A may be interesting to you. Rather than merely divide by 2 for unsigned ints, the answers are various forms of divide by 'n' for signed ints that implement "Banker's Rounding" (ie: round to nearest even when exactly one-half... There ya go...

@pts, Instead of for (unsigned x = 60; x < 80; ++x), I tried for (unsigned x = UINT_MAX; x > UINT_MAX - 80; x--).  FNCDEF(weijun,even) and FNCDEF(john,even) had mis-matches.

@pts Consider for (unsigned x = 0; x < 80; ++x) { for (unsigned a = 0; a < 32; ++a) {   dotest(even_list, x, a); dotest(even_list, UINT_MAX - x, a); } } for testing.

This is slightly simpler in terms of number of operators (10 vs 12, counting the == in the if condition in the question):
unsigned rshift_round_towards_even(unsigned x, unsigned a) {
    return (x && a) ? ((((x - !((x >> a) & 1)) >> (a - 1)) + 1) >> 1) : x;
}

Yes, one of the operators is the ternary operator, but then the question (now) has a full-blown if statement that this does not, and that I also haven't represented in the count.
The logic goes like this:

if either x or a is zero then the result is x. This is special-cased via a ternary operation to avoid underflows in the main expression.

the first alternative of the ternary is a modified version of this shift with round-half-up:
((x >> (a - 1)) + 1) >> 1

which itself involves an integer variation on floor(f + 0.5).  To convert that into round-to-nearest, half-to-even, 1 is subtracted from the original x when the half-to-even part requires rounding down, which is when !((x >> a) & 1) evaluates to 1.  That changes the result of the round-to nearest only when the original is at exactly the halfway point.


Addendum
As @IanAbbott alluded to in comments, the above has undefined behavior when a is greater than or equal to the number of value bits in type unsigned int, per explicit provision of the language specifications for the >> operator.  The same applies to the alternative given in the question, so it may not be an issue, but if such inputs are contemplated, and if the target implementation(s) cannot be relied upon to produce the wanted behavior for such operands, then additional effort is required.
If a version safe for large a is required, then I might implement it as a separate wrapper, maybe something like:
// Assumes no padding bits in unsigned int:
#define UINT_BITS (sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT)

unsigned rshift_round_towards_even_safe(unsigned x, unsigned a) {
    if (a < UINT_BITS) return rshift_round_towards_even(x, a);
    if (a > UINT_BITS) return 0;
    return (x > ((UINT_MAX >> 1) + 1));
}

That could be restructured as a single expression via ternary operators, if desired, and the expression from rshift_round_towards_even could be inlined into it as well, if desired.

+1, but FWIW, if I ran into code in a professional setting that needed to be that dense for performance reasons, I'd expect your full paragraph explaining what it's doing be in comments.  Along with a nice set of unit tests that make sure it'll work if someone decides to modify it in the future.

And I would not blame you at all for that, @AndrewHenle.  I have emulated the OP's style, but if I were writing it for my own use then I would probably throw in a couple of intermediate variables, and I would definitely put an explanation in the code itself.  And I would probably write an if instead of using a ternary expression, at least initially.  Unit tests almost go without saying.

I created a unit test program (since pts didn't) and posted it in an answer. It has cut-and-paste from most answers here (yours included).

I've upvoted all correct answers and the benchmark program. I've chosen to accept this answer for its simplificity (to me). I was hoping for something much simpler (and shorter) than any of the solutions (including my own), but it looks like such complexity is needed.

If large a values (a >= UINT_WIDTH) could be encountered, then return a < UINT_WIDTH ? your_expression : a > UINT_WIDTH ? 0 : x > 1U << (UINT_WIDTH - 1);. (It may need a workaround to define UINT_WIDTH if the implementation does not support C23.) E.g. if UINT_WIDTH is 32 and a is 32, then it returns x > 0x80000000. If a > UINT_WIDTH it returns 0.

Fair enough, @IanAbbott, I acknowledge that the function presented in this answer has UB in exactly the cases where plain x >> a has UB.  As the OP's starting variant also does.  I have added an addendum to discuss the matter.

I've created a test harness/diagnostic program.
I've included all versions of this writing (pts, chux, Weijun, John, Simon).
Sorry if I've missed anyone.
However, the test program is [easily(?)] extensible ... Feel free to download the file, and add your own version of the function to the test.
The test program compares all versions for correctness, using pts's version as the reference.
It also reports benchmark timings.

Here is the source code. [I've shortened the names to avoid descent into madness :-)]:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned
pts_down(unsigned x, unsigned a)
{
    return x >> a;
}

unsigned
pts_up(unsigned x, unsigned a)
{
    return (x >> a) + ((x & ((1 << a) - 1)) != 0);
}

unsigned
pts_halfway(unsigned x, unsigned a)
{
    if (a == 0) return x;
    return (x >> a) + ((x >> (a - 1)) & 1);
}

unsigned
pts_even(unsigned x, unsigned a)
{
    if (a == 0) return x;
    return (x >> a) + ((x >> (a - ((x & ((1 << a) - 1)) != 1 << (a - 1)))) & 1);
}

unsigned
chux_even(unsigned x, unsigned a)
{
    unsigned shifted_lsbit_mask = 1u << a;
    unsigned bits_shifted_out_mask = shifted_lsbit_mask - 1u;
    unsigned bits_shifted_out = bits_shifted_out_mask & x;
    unsigned is_even = !(shifted_lsbit_mask & x);
    unsigned carry = (bits_shifted_out + is_even) > (bits_shifted_out_mask >> 1);
    return (x >> a) + carry;
}

unsigned
weijun_even(unsigned x, unsigned a)
{
    unsigned y = (1u << a) >> 1u;
    unsigned z = x + y;
    unsigned e = (__builtin_ffs(z) == a + ! !a);
    return (z >> a) - e;
}

unsigned
john_even(unsigned x, unsigned a)
{
    return (x && a) ? ((((x - !((x >> a) & 1)) >> (a - 1)) + 1) >> 1) : x;
}

unsigned
simon_even(unsigned x, unsigned a)
{
/* Author : Simon Goater May 2024
a bits to right of pipe.
round down
...0|000...000 - ...0|100...000
round up (+1)
...0|100...001 - ...0|111...111
round down
...1|000...000 - ...1|011...111
round up (+1)
...1|100...000 - ...1|111...111
*/
    if (a == 0)
        return x;
    unsigned am1 = (a - 1);
    unsigned t = x >> am1;

    return (t >> 1) + (t & 1) - (x == ((((t >> 2) << 2) | 1) << am1));
}

typedef unsigned (*fncptr_p)(unsigned,unsigned);

struct fncdef {
    const char *fnc_sym;                // function name
    fncptr_p fnc_ptr;                   // pointer to function
    double fnc_elap;                    // best elapsed time
};

#define FNCDEF(_who,_fnc) \
    { .fnc_sym = #_who, .fnc_ptr = _who##_##_fnc }

// list of all "rshift_round_towards_even" functions
struct fncdef even_list[] = {
    FNCDEF(pts,even),
    FNCDEF(weijun,even),
    FNCDEF(chux,even),
    FNCDEF(john,even),
    FNCDEF(simon,even),
    { .fnc_sym = NULL }
};

int fail;                               // if a test in a group fails

// tscgetf -- get fractional elapsed seconds
double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

#ifndef BEST
#define BEST        5
#endif

#ifndef ITER
#define ITER        10000
#endif

// dofnc -- speed test single function
unsigned
dofnc(struct fncdef *fnc,unsigned x,unsigned a)
{
    double tscbeg;
    double tscend;
    double tscbest = 1e9;
    unsigned ret;

    // select the best time on N runs
    for (int best = 1;  best <= BEST;  ++best) {
        tscbeg = tscgetf();

        // interate enough to get larger elapsed time
        for (int iter = ITER;  iter >= 0;  --iter)
            ret = fnc->fnc_ptr(x,a);

        tscend = tscgetf();
        tscend -= tscbeg;

        // to mitigate cache hot/cold effects and timeslicing, use the shortest
        // time
        if (tscend < tscbest)
            tscbest = tscend;
    }

    fnc->fnc_elap = tscend;

    return ret;
}

// dotest -- run test on all functions
void
dotest(struct fncdef *fnclist,unsigned x,unsigned a)
{

    printf("\n");
    printf("dotest: x=%u/%8.8X a=%u/%8.8X\n",x,x,a,1u << a);

    fail = 0;

    unsigned ref = 0;

    // try all functions
    for (struct fncdef *fnc = fnclist;  fnc->fnc_sym != NULL;  ++fnc) {
        // run current function
        unsigned tst = dofnc(fnc,x,a);

        // first function in list is the reference (i.e. pts's)
        if (fnc == fnclist)
            ref = tst;

        int pass = (tst == ref);
        printf("%.9f %s: x=%u a=%u ref=%u tst=%u %s\n",
            fnc->fnc_elap,fnc->fnc_sym,x,a,ref,tst,pass ? "" : " (FAIL!!!)");

        fail += (! pass);

#if 0
        if (! pass)
            exit(1);
#endif
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    // small test
    for (unsigned x = 60;  x < 80;  ++x) {
        for (unsigned a = 0;  a < 3;  ++a)
            dotest(even_list,x,a);
    }

#if 0
    for (unsigned x = 0;  x < 80;  ++x) {
        for (unsigned a = 0;  a < 32;  ++a)
            dotest(even_list,x,a);
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}


Compiled with -O2 on my system, the results are:

dotest: x=60/0000003C a=0/00000001
0.000028775 pts: x=60 a=0 ref=60 tst=60
0.000041352 weijun: x=60 a=0 ref=60 tst=60
0.000039079 chux: x=60 a=0 ref=60 tst=61  (FAIL!!!)
0.000028969 john: x=60 a=0 ref=60 tst=60
0.000028788 simon: x=60 a=0 ref=60 tst=60

dotest: x=60/0000003C a=1/00000002
0.000039513 pts: x=60 a=1 ref=30 tst=30
0.000041399 weijun: x=60 a=1 ref=30 tst=30
0.000032393 chux: x=60 a=1 ref=30 tst=31  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032340 john: x=60 a=1 ref=30 tst=30
0.000035949 simon: x=60 a=1 ref=30 tst=30

dotest: x=60/0000003C a=2/00000004
0.000042180 pts: x=60 a=2 ref=15 tst=15
0.000041362 weijun: x=60 a=2 ref=15 tst=15
0.000032335 chux: x=60 a=2 ref=15 tst=15
0.000032333 john: x=60 a=2 ref=15 tst=15
0.000035947 simon: x=60 a=2 ref=15 tst=15

dotest: x=61/0000003D a=0/00000001
0.000028740 pts: x=61 a=0 ref=61 tst=61
0.000041312 weijun: x=61 a=0 ref=61 tst=61
0.000032334 chux: x=61 a=0 ref=61 tst=61
0.000028742 john: x=61 a=0 ref=61 tst=61
0.000028741 simon: x=61 a=0 ref=61 tst=61

dotest: x=61/0000003D a=1/00000002
0.000039519 pts: x=61 a=1 ref=30 tst=30
0.000041312 weijun: x=61 a=1 ref=30 tst=30
0.000032335 chux: x=61 a=1 ref=30 tst=31  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032340 john: x=61 a=1 ref=30 tst=30
0.000035948 simon: x=61 a=1 ref=30 tst=30

dotest: x=61/0000003D a=2/00000004
0.000039573 pts: x=61 a=2 ref=15 tst=15
0.000041865 weijun: x=61 a=2 ref=15 tst=15
0.000032507 chux: x=61 a=2 ref=15 tst=15
0.000032339 john: x=61 a=2 ref=15 tst=15
0.000035954 simon: x=61 a=2 ref=15 tst=15

dotest: x=62/0000003E a=0/00000001
0.000028749 pts: x=62 a=0 ref=62 tst=62
0.000041312 weijun: x=62 a=0 ref=62 tst=62
0.000032342 chux: x=62 a=0 ref=62 tst=63  (FAIL!!!)
0.000028742 john: x=62 a=0 ref=62 tst=62
0.000028742 simon: x=62 a=0 ref=62 tst=62

dotest: x=62/0000003E a=1/00000002
0.000039519 pts: x=62 a=1 ref=31 tst=31
0.000041312 weijun: x=62 a=1 ref=31 tst=31
0.000032342 chux: x=62 a=1 ref=31 tst=31
0.000032340 john: x=62 a=1 ref=31 tst=31
0.000035949 simon: x=62 a=1 ref=31 tst=31

dotest: x=62/0000003E a=2/00000004
0.000098737 pts: x=62 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000041365 weijun: x=62 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000032342 chux: x=62 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000032333 john: x=62 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000035949 simon: x=62 a=2 ref=16 tst=16

dotest: x=63/0000003F a=0/00000001
0.000028740 pts: x=63 a=0 ref=63 tst=63
0.000041359 weijun: x=63 a=0 ref=63 tst=63
0.000032337 chux: x=63 a=0 ref=63 tst=63
0.000028742 john: x=63 a=0 ref=63 tst=63
0.000028742 simon: x=63 a=0 ref=63 tst=63

dotest: x=63/0000003F a=1/00000002
0.000039518 pts: x=63 a=1 ref=32 tst=32
0.000061065 weijun: x=63 a=1 ref=32 tst=32
0.000067555 chux: x=63 a=1 ref=32 tst=32
0.000042803 john: x=63 a=1 ref=32 tst=32
0.000049941 simon: x=63 a=1 ref=32 tst=32

dotest: x=63/0000003F a=2/00000004
0.000039520 pts: x=63 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000042470 weijun: x=63 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000032342 chux: x=63 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000032341 john: x=63 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000092078 simon: x=63 a=2 ref=16 tst=16

dotest: x=64/00000040 a=0/00000001
0.000028742 pts: x=64 a=0 ref=64 tst=64
0.000041311 weijun: x=64 a=0 ref=64 tst=64
0.000032342 chux: x=64 a=0 ref=64 tst=65  (FAIL!!!)
0.000028749 john: x=64 a=0 ref=64 tst=64
0.000028748 simon: x=64 a=0 ref=64 tst=64

dotest: x=64/00000040 a=1/00000002
0.000039520 pts: x=64 a=1 ref=32 tst=32
0.000041311 weijun: x=64 a=1 ref=32 tst=32
0.000032336 chux: x=64 a=1 ref=32 tst=33  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032340 john: x=64 a=1 ref=32 tst=32
0.000035955 simon: x=64 a=1 ref=32 tst=32

dotest: x=64/00000040 a=2/00000004
0.000039518 pts: x=64 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000041310 weijun: x=64 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000032342 chux: x=64 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000032333 john: x=64 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000035949 simon: x=64 a=2 ref=16 tst=16

dotest: x=65/00000041 a=0/00000001
0.000028748 pts: x=65 a=0 ref=65 tst=65
0.000041313 weijun: x=65 a=0 ref=65 tst=65
0.000032342 chux: x=65 a=0 ref=65 tst=65
0.000028748 john: x=65 a=0 ref=65 tst=65
0.000028748 simon: x=65 a=0 ref=65 tst=65

dotest: x=65/00000041 a=1/00000002
0.000039512 pts: x=65 a=1 ref=32 tst=32
0.000041311 weijun: x=65 a=1 ref=32 tst=32
0.000032343 chux: x=65 a=1 ref=32 tst=33  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032340 john: x=65 a=1 ref=32 tst=32
0.000035979 simon: x=65 a=1 ref=32 tst=32

dotest: x=65/00000041 a=2/00000004
0.000039520 pts: x=65 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000041359 weijun: x=65 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000032336 chux: x=65 a=2 ref=16 tst=17  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032333 john: x=65 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000035988 simon: x=65 a=2 ref=16 tst=16

dotest: x=66/00000042 a=0/00000001
0.000028742 pts: x=66 a=0 ref=66 tst=66
0.000041311 weijun: x=66 a=0 ref=66 tst=66
0.000032335 chux: x=66 a=0 ref=66 tst=67  (FAIL!!!)
0.000028825 john: x=66 a=0 ref=66 tst=66
0.000028742 simon: x=66 a=0 ref=66 tst=66

dotest: x=66/00000042 a=1/00000002
0.000039520 pts: x=66 a=1 ref=33 tst=33
0.000041311 weijun: x=66 a=1 ref=33 tst=33
0.000032423 chux: x=66 a=1 ref=33 tst=33
0.000046130 john: x=66 a=1 ref=33 tst=33
0.000035955 simon: x=66 a=1 ref=33 tst=33

dotest: x=66/00000042 a=2/00000004
0.000039559 pts: x=66 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000041311 weijun: x=66 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000032343 chux: x=66 a=2 ref=16 tst=17  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032335 john: x=66 a=2 ref=16 tst=16
0.000036024 simon: x=66 a=2 ref=16 tst=16

dotest: x=67/00000043 a=0/00000001
0.000028788 pts: x=67 a=0 ref=67 tst=67
0.000041437 weijun: x=67 a=0 ref=67 tst=67
0.000032341 chux: x=67 a=0 ref=67 tst=67
0.000028782 john: x=67 a=0 ref=67 tst=67
0.000092458 simon: x=67 a=0 ref=67 tst=67

dotest: x=67/00000043 a=1/00000002
0.000039606 pts: x=67 a=1 ref=34 tst=34
0.000041399 weijun: x=67 a=1 ref=34 tst=34
0.000032384 chux: x=67 a=1 ref=34 tst=34
0.000032335 john: x=67 a=1 ref=34 tst=34
0.000035948 simon: x=67 a=1 ref=34 tst=34

dotest: x=67/00000043 a=2/00000004
0.000039513 pts: x=67 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000041312 weijun: x=67 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000032336 chux: x=67 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000032382 john: x=67 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000035954 simon: x=67 a=2 ref=17 tst=17

dotest: x=68/00000044 a=0/00000001
0.000028748 pts: x=68 a=0 ref=68 tst=68
0.000041359 weijun: x=68 a=0 ref=68 tst=68
0.000032342 chux: x=68 a=0 ref=68 tst=69  (FAIL!!!)
0.000028741 john: x=68 a=0 ref=68 tst=68
0.000028747 simon: x=68 a=0 ref=68 tst=68

dotest: x=68/00000044 a=1/00000002
0.000039563 pts: x=68 a=1 ref=34 tst=34
0.000041312 weijun: x=68 a=1 ref=34 tst=34
0.000032460 chux: x=68 a=1 ref=34 tst=35  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032333 john: x=68 a=1 ref=34 tst=34
0.000035954 simon: x=68 a=1 ref=34 tst=34

dotest: x=68/00000044 a=2/00000004
0.000039513 pts: x=68 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000041358 weijun: x=68 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000041627 chux: x=68 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000032334 john: x=68 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000035955 simon: x=68 a=2 ref=17 tst=17

dotest: x=69/00000045 a=0/00000001
0.000028742 pts: x=69 a=0 ref=69 tst=69
0.000041312 weijun: x=69 a=0 ref=69 tst=69
0.000032335 chux: x=69 a=0 ref=69 tst=69
0.000028742 john: x=69 a=0 ref=69 tst=69
0.000028742 simon: x=69 a=0 ref=69 tst=69

dotest: x=69/00000045 a=1/00000002
0.000039512 pts: x=69 a=1 ref=34 tst=34
0.000041312 weijun: x=69 a=1 ref=34 tst=34
0.000032335 chux: x=69 a=1 ref=34 tst=35  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032340 john: x=69 a=1 ref=34 tst=34
0.000035954 simon: x=69 a=1 ref=34 tst=34

dotest: x=69/00000045 a=2/00000004
0.000039520 pts: x=69 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000041311 weijun: x=69 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000095090 chux: x=69 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000032341 john: x=69 a=2 ref=17 tst=17
0.000035954 simon: x=69 a=2 ref=17 tst=17

dotest: x=70/00000046 a=0/00000001
0.000028742 pts: x=70 a=0 ref=70 tst=70
0.000041312 weijun: x=70 a=0 ref=70 tst=70
0.000032342 chux: x=70 a=0 ref=70 tst=71  (FAIL!!!)
0.000028749 john: x=70 a=0 ref=70 tst=70
0.000028742 simon: x=70 a=0 ref=70 tst=70

dotest: x=70/00000046 a=1/00000002
0.000039513 pts: x=70 a=1 ref=35 tst=35
0.000041311 weijun: x=70 a=1 ref=35 tst=35
0.000032341 chux: x=70 a=1 ref=35 tst=35
0.000034652 john: x=70 a=1 ref=35 tst=35
0.000056274 simon: x=70 a=1 ref=35 tst=35

dotest: x=70/00000046 a=2/00000004
0.000039519 pts: x=70 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000041313 weijun: x=70 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000032335 chux: x=70 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000032334 john: x=70 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000035955 simon: x=70 a=2 ref=18 tst=18

dotest: x=71/00000047 a=0/00000001
0.000028741 pts: x=71 a=0 ref=71 tst=71
0.000041311 weijun: x=71 a=0 ref=71 tst=71
0.000032342 chux: x=71 a=0 ref=71 tst=71
0.000028749 john: x=71 a=0 ref=71 tst=71
0.000028742 simon: x=71 a=0 ref=71 tst=71

dotest: x=71/00000047 a=1/00000002
0.000039513 pts: x=71 a=1 ref=36 tst=36
0.000041312 weijun: x=71 a=1 ref=36 tst=36
0.000032342 chux: x=71 a=1 ref=36 tst=36
0.000032339 john: x=71 a=1 ref=36 tst=36
0.000099147 simon: x=71 a=1 ref=36 tst=36

dotest: x=71/00000047 a=2/00000004
0.000039520 pts: x=71 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000041319 weijun: x=71 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000032433 chux: x=71 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000032386 john: x=71 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000036001 simon: x=71 a=2 ref=18 tst=18

dotest: x=72/00000048 a=0/00000001
0.000028786 pts: x=72 a=0 ref=72 tst=72
0.000041433 weijun: x=72 a=0 ref=72 tst=72
0.000032335 chux: x=72 a=0 ref=72 tst=73  (FAIL!!!)
0.000028748 john: x=72 a=0 ref=72 tst=72
0.000028807 simon: x=72 a=0 ref=72 tst=72

dotest: x=72/00000048 a=1/00000002
0.000042874 pts: x=72 a=1 ref=36 tst=36
0.000041399 weijun: x=72 a=1 ref=36 tst=36
0.000032470 chux: x=72 a=1 ref=36 tst=37  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032465 john: x=72 a=1 ref=36 tst=36
0.000036202 simon: x=72 a=1 ref=36 tst=36

dotest: x=72/00000048 a=2/00000004
0.000039817 pts: x=72 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000041562 weijun: x=72 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000032622 chux: x=72 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000032621 john: x=72 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000036316 simon: x=72 a=2 ref=18 tst=18

dotest: x=73/00000049 a=0/00000001
0.000029074 pts: x=73 a=0 ref=73 tst=73
0.000041520 weijun: x=73 a=0 ref=73 tst=73
0.000032469 chux: x=73 a=0 ref=73 tst=73
0.000028788 john: x=73 a=0 ref=73 tst=73
0.000028742 simon: x=73 a=0 ref=73 tst=73

dotest: x=73/00000049 a=1/00000002
0.000039742 pts: x=73 a=1 ref=36 tst=36
0.000044357 weijun: x=73 a=1 ref=36 tst=36
0.000032381 chux: x=73 a=1 ref=36 tst=37  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032477 john: x=73 a=1 ref=36 tst=36
0.000035949 simon: x=73 a=1 ref=36 tst=36

dotest: x=73/00000049 a=2/00000004
0.000039519 pts: x=73 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000041433 weijun: x=73 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000032385 chux: x=73 a=2 ref=18 tst=19  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032382 john: x=73 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000036191 simon: x=73 a=2 ref=18 tst=18

dotest: x=74/0000004A a=0/00000001
0.000028905 pts: x=74 a=0 ref=74 tst=74
0.000041318 weijun: x=74 a=0 ref=74 tst=74
0.000032592 chux: x=74 a=0 ref=74 tst=75  (FAIL!!!)
0.000028742 john: x=74 a=0 ref=74 tst=74
0.000028815 simon: x=74 a=0 ref=74 tst=74

dotest: x=74/0000004A a=1/00000002
0.000039622 pts: x=74 a=1 ref=37 tst=37
0.000041520 weijun: x=74 a=1 ref=37 tst=37
0.000032342 chux: x=74 a=1 ref=37 tst=37
0.000032381 john: x=74 a=1 ref=37 tst=37
0.000035955 simon: x=74 a=1 ref=37 tst=37

dotest: x=74/0000004A a=2/00000004
0.000039520 pts: x=74 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000041352 weijun: x=74 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000032389 chux: x=74 a=2 ref=18 tst=19  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032530 john: x=74 a=2 ref=18 tst=18
0.000036000 simon: x=74 a=2 ref=18 tst=18

dotest: x=75/0000004B a=0/00000001
0.000028742 pts: x=75 a=0 ref=75 tst=75
0.000041521 weijun: x=75 a=0 ref=75 tst=75
0.000032429 chux: x=75 a=0 ref=75 tst=75
0.000028748 john: x=75 a=0 ref=75 tst=75
0.000031068 simon: x=75 a=0 ref=75 tst=75

dotest: x=75/0000004B a=1/00000002
0.000039513 pts: x=75 a=1 ref=38 tst=38
0.000041400 weijun: x=75 a=1 ref=38 tst=38
0.000032342 chux: x=75 a=1 ref=38 tst=38
0.000032427 john: x=75 a=1 ref=38 tst=38
0.000035955 simon: x=75 a=1 ref=38 tst=38

dotest: x=75/0000004B a=2/00000004
0.000039514 pts: x=75 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000041317 weijun: x=75 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000032386 chux: x=75 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000032341 john: x=75 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000035955 simon: x=75 a=2 ref=19 tst=19

dotest: x=76/0000004C a=0/00000001
0.000028787 pts: x=76 a=0 ref=76 tst=76
0.000041312 weijun: x=76 a=0 ref=76 tst=76
0.000032342 chux: x=76 a=0 ref=76 tst=77  (FAIL!!!)
0.000028742 john: x=76 a=0 ref=76 tst=76
0.000028749 simon: x=76 a=0 ref=76 tst=76

dotest: x=76/0000004C a=1/00000002
0.000039520 pts: x=76 a=1 ref=38 tst=38
0.000041318 weijun: x=76 a=1 ref=38 tst=38
0.000032342 chux: x=76 a=1 ref=38 tst=39  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032334 john: x=76 a=1 ref=38 tst=38
0.000036043 simon: x=76 a=1 ref=38 tst=38

dotest: x=76/0000004C a=2/00000004
0.000039520 pts: x=76 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000041312 weijun: x=76 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000032342 chux: x=76 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000032334 john: x=76 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000035955 simon: x=76 a=2 ref=19 tst=19

dotest: x=77/0000004D a=0/00000001
0.000028748 pts: x=77 a=0 ref=77 tst=77
0.000041484 weijun: x=77 a=0 ref=77 tst=77
0.000032382 chux: x=77 a=0 ref=77 tst=77
0.000028782 john: x=77 a=0 ref=77 tst=77
0.000028742 simon: x=77 a=0 ref=77 tst=77

dotest: x=77/0000004D a=1/00000002
0.000039518 pts: x=77 a=1 ref=38 tst=38
0.000041312 weijun: x=77 a=1 ref=38 tst=38
0.000032341 chux: x=77 a=1 ref=38 tst=39  (FAIL!!!)
0.000032382 john: x=77 a=1 ref=38 tst=38
0.000035955 simon: x=77 a=1 ref=38 tst=38

dotest: x=77/0000004D a=2/00000004
0.000039513 pts: x=77 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000041359 weijun: x=77 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000032343 chux: x=77 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000032339 john: x=77 a=2 ref=19 tst=19
0.000035956 simon: x=77 a=2 ref=19 tst=19

dotest: x=78/0000004E a=0/00000001
0.000028747 pts: x=78 a=0 ref=78 tst=78
0.000041318 weijun: x=78 a=0 ref=78 tst=78
0.000032336 chux: x=78 a=0 ref=78 tst=79  (FAIL!!!)
0.000028742 john: x=78 a=0 ref=78 tst=78
0.000028742 simon: x=78 a=0 ref=78 tst=78

dotest: x=78/0000004E a=1/00000002
0.000039520 pts: x=78 a=1 ref=39 tst=39
0.000041312 weijun: x=78 a=1 ref=39 tst=39
0.000032341 chux: x=78 a=1 ref=39 tst=39
0.000032339 john: x=78 a=1 ref=39 tst=39
0.000035949 simon: x=78 a=1 ref=39 tst=39

dotest: x=78/0000004E a=2/00000004
0.000039562 pts: x=78 a=2 ref=20 tst=20
0.000041312 weijun: x=78 a=2 ref=20 tst=20
0.000032385 chux: x=78 a=2 ref=20 tst=20
0.000032333 john: x=78 a=2 ref=20 tst=20
0.000035948 simon: x=78 a=2 ref=20 tst=20

dotest: x=79/0000004F a=0/00000001
0.000028742 pts: x=79 a=0 ref=79 tst=79
0.000041311 weijun: x=79 a=0 ref=79 tst=79
0.000032335 chux: x=79 a=0 ref=79 tst=79
0.000028748 john: x=79 a=0 ref=79 tst=79
0.000028748 simon: x=79 a=0 ref=79 tst=79

dotest: x=79/0000004F a=1/00000002
0.000039518 pts: x=79 a=1 ref=40 tst=40
0.000041363 weijun: x=79 a=1 ref=40 tst=40
0.000032336 chux: x=79 a=1 ref=40 tst=40
0.000032341 john: x=79 a=1 ref=40 tst=40
0.000035984 simon: x=79 a=1 ref=40 tst=40

dotest: x=79/0000004F a=2/00000004
0.000039521 pts: x=79 a=2 ref=20 tst=20
0.000041311 weijun: x=79 a=2 ref=20 tst=20
0.000039350 chux: x=79 a=2 ref=20 tst=20
0.000032340 john: x=79 a=2 ref=20 tst=20
0.000035948 simon: x=79 a=2 ref=20 tst=20


Here is the redacted disassembly for -O2:
00000000004011a0 <chux_even>:
  4011a0:   89 f1                   mov    %esi,%ecx
  4011a2:   ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
  4011a7:   d3 e2                   shl    %cl,%edx
  4011a9:   85 fa                   test   %edi,%edx
  4011ab:   8d 42 ff                lea    -0x1(%rdx),%eax
  4011ae:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
  4011b0:   0f 94 c2                sete   %dl
  4011b3:   d1 e8                   shr    %eax
  4011b5:   21 fe                   and    %edi,%esi
  4011b7:   0f b6 d2                movzbl %dl,%edx
  4011ba:   01 f2                   add    %esi,%edx
  4011bc:   39 c2                   cmp    %eax,%edx
  4011be:   0f 97 c0                seta   %al
  4011c1:   d3 ef                   shr    %cl,%edi
  4011c3:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
  4011c6:   01 f8                   add    %edi,%eax
  4011c8:   c3                      retq
  4011c9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

00000000004011d0 <weijun_even>:
  4011d0:   89 f1                   mov    %esi,%ecx
  4011d2:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  4011d7:   be ff ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffff,%esi
  4011dc:   d3 e0                   shl    %cl,%eax
  4011de:   d1 e8                   shr    %eax
  4011e0:   01 f8                   add    %edi,%eax
  4011e2:   0f bc d0                bsf    %eax,%edx
  4011e5:   0f 44 d6                cmove  %esi,%edx
  4011e8:   d3 e8                   shr    %cl,%eax
  4011ea:   31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
  4011ec:   83 c2 01                add    $0x1,%edx
  4011ef:   85 c9                   test   %ecx,%ecx
  4011f1:   40 0f 95 c6             setne  %sil
  4011f5:   01 f1                   add    %esi,%ecx
  4011f7:   39 d1                   cmp    %edx,%ecx
  4011f9:   0f 94 c2                sete   %dl
  4011fc:   0f b6 d2                movzbl %dl,%edx
  4011ff:   29 d0                   sub    %edx,%eax
  401201:   c3                      retq
  401202:   66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data16 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  401209:   00 00 00 00
  40120d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)

0000000000401210 <pts_even>:
  401210:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
  401212:   85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
  401214:   74 2e                   je     401244 <L00>
  401216:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  40121b:   89 f1                   mov    %esi,%ecx
  40121d:   89 fa                   mov    %edi,%edx
  40121f:   d3 e2                   shl    %cl,%edx
  401221:   8d 4e ff                lea    -0x1(%rsi),%ecx
  401224:   83 ea 01                sub    $0x1,%edx
  401227:   d3 e7                   shl    %cl,%edi
  401229:   89 f1                   mov    %esi,%ecx
  40122b:   21 c2                   and    %eax,%edx
  40122d:   39 fa                   cmp    %edi,%edx
  40122f:   0f 95 c2                setne  %dl
  401232:   0f b6 d2                movzbl %dl,%edx
  401235:   29 d1                   sub    %edx,%ecx
  401237:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
  401239:   d3 ea                   shr    %cl,%edx
  40123b:   89 f1                   mov    %esi,%ecx
  40123d:   83 e2 01                and    $0x1,%edx
  401240:   d3 e8                   shr    %cl,%eax
  401242:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
  401244:L00    c3                      retq
  401245:   66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data16 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40124c:   00 00 00 00

0000000000401250 <john_even>:
  401250:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
  401252:   74 1b                   je     40126f <L00>
  401254:   85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
  401256:   74 17                   je     40126f <L00>
  401258:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
  40125a:   89 f1                   mov    %esi,%ecx
  40125c:   d3 e8                   shr    %cl,%eax
  40125e:   8d 4e ff                lea    -0x1(%rsi),%ecx
  401261:   f7 d0                   not    %eax
  401263:   83 e0 01                and    $0x1,%eax
  401266:   29 c7                   sub    %eax,%edi
  401268:   d3 ef                   shr    %cl,%edi
  40126a:   83 c7 01                add    $0x1,%edi
  40126d:   d1 ef                   shr    %edi
  40126f:L00    89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
  401271:   c3                      retq
  401272:   66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data16 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  401279:   00 00 00 00
  40127d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)

0000000000401280 <simon_even>:
  401280:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
  401282:   85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
  401284:   74 26                   je     4012ac <L00>
  401286:   8d 4e ff                lea    -0x1(%rsi),%ecx
  401289:   89 fa                   mov    %edi,%edx
  40128b:   d3 ea                   shr    %cl,%edx
  40128d:   89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
  40128f:   89 d7                   mov    %edx,%edi
  401291:   83 e2 fc                and    $0xfffffffc,%edx
  401294:   83 ca 01                or     $0x1,%edx
  401297:   d1 ee                   shr    %esi
  401299:   83 e7 01                and    $0x1,%edi
  40129c:   d3 e2                   shl    %cl,%edx
  40129e:   01 fe                   add    %edi,%esi
  4012a0:   39 c2                   cmp    %eax,%edx
  4012a2:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al
  4012a5:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
  4012a8:   29 c6                   sub    %eax,%esi
  4012aa:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
  4012ac:L00    c3                      retq
  4012ad:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)


The problem with Weijun's function I mentioned in the comments was not detected by this test.

@SimonGoater From: I got an error at 3904095504 31? Does this mean these are the two arguments to the function? I omitted large test ranges for brevity and fitting the output in a answer (30,000 chars). It's easy to add a dotest(even_list,3904095504,31); call to main

Functionality now passes OP's test harness.
With optimizations turned on performs favorably with others.

Problems with existing code
1 << a is undefined behavior (UB) when a signed 1 is shifted into the sign bit.  Use 1u << a.
rshift_round_halfway(x , 0) is UB as x >> (a - 1) is like x >> UINT_MAX and thus a very large shift.
Tested alternate for rshift_round_towards_even()
unsigned rshift_round_towards_even_alt(unsigned x, unsigned a) {
  unsigned shifted_lsbit_mask = 1u << a;
  unsigned bits_shifted_out = (shifted_lsbit_mask - 1u) & x;
  bool is_odd = shifted_lsbit_mask & x;
  unsigned carry = (bits_shifted_out*2U | is_odd) > shifted_lsbit_mask;
  return (x >> a) + carry;
}


When compiling, I get: ts.c:34:51: error: ‘lsbit_shifted_out_mask’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘bits_shifted_out_mask’?

Thank you for trying to help! This solution is not any simpler than my original, in fact it's a bit longer, even after inlining the local variables. It also doesn't compile.

Thank you for flagging the undefined behavior in the code within the question. I've fixed that code based on your suggestions.

I corrected the typo according to the error message. I wrote a diagnostic program that compares OP's original functions against possible candidates  and it fails some tests but passes others.

@pts "This solution is not any simpler than my original, in fact it's a bit longer" --> are you comparing source code length, emitted code length, code speed or what?  Do you compile with optimizations on?

@CraigEstey Compiler error fixed.  Too bad OP did not post a test harness.  Which of your tests failed here?

I built a test harness (for two functions). I'm generalizing it, will add your test [and all others I find here]. It will test for correctness and do benchmarking. I'll post it in an answer when I get it working. People will be able to pull it, add their own new tests.

I got a difference from OP's with 2383496516 3 with your function. 297937064 vs 297937065.

@SimonGoater Code updated.  Passes OP's test harness.

Good job. It's a bit faster than mine in my test program.

Not sure whether this counts as better, but if you are open to intrinsics,
unsigned rshift_round_towards_even(unsigned x, unsigned a) {
    unsigned y = (1u << a) >> 1u;
    unsigned z = x + y;
    unsigned e = (__builtin_ffs(z) == a + !!a);
    return (z >> a) - e;
}

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/8cjbnnxba

Thank you! I'm interested in C99 only, so I'm not accepting this answer, but it's nice to know that __builtin_ffs is useful for solving this.

I got an error at 3904095504 31 with this function. Answer should be 2, this gives 0. It's also slightly slower on my machine than the OPs.

@SimonGoater That's due to wrapping for huge numbers, using unsigned long for y and z should fix it. I probably won't update the code in the answer until I fix other issues with it.

FWIW I came up with this. I benchmarked it at slightly slower than John Bollinger's but I think it's easier to understand. My benchmark didn't impose strict serial dependency though so it might be different in different tests and hardware. Both are approx 3x faster in my tests than the OP's original. Since were having some fun trying to squeeze as much performance out of the instructions available, and maybe someone is going to do some more sophisticated benchmarks, I thought it would be fun to throw mine into the ring.
unsigned rshift_round_towards_even(unsigned x, unsigned a) {
/* Author : Simon Goater May 2024
a bits to right of pipe. 
round down
...0|000...000 - ...0|100...000
round up (+1)
...0|100...001 - ...0|111...111
round down
...1|000...000 - ...1|011...111
round up (+1)
...1|100...000 - ...1|111...111
*/
  if (a == 0) return x;
  unsigned am1 = (a - 1);
  unsigned t = x >> am1;
  return (t >> 1) + (t & 1) - (x == ((((t >> 2) << 2) | 1) << am1));
}

